# Query Takes too long to Complete

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table with 900k+ records

it takes a minute or more to run this query:

```
SELECT
  t.user_id,
  SUM(t.direction = "i") AS 'num_in',
  SUM(t.direction = "o") AS 'num_out'
FROM tbl_user_reports t
WHERE t.bound_time BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-02-28'
GROUP BY t.user_id
HAVING t.user_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY num_in DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

can you tell me how to query the result faster?

-- more info --
structure:

```
id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
subscriber varchar(255) NULL
user_id int(11) unsigned NULL
carrier_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
pool_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
service_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
persona_id int(11) unsigned NULL
inbound_id int(11) unsigned NULL
outbound_id int(11) unsigned NULL
bound_time datetime NOT NULL
direction varchar(1) NOT NULL
```

indexes:

```
bound_timebound_time
FK_tbl_user_reportspersona_id
FK_tbl_user_reports_messageinbound_id
FK_tbl_user_reports_serviceservice_id
FK_tbl_user_reports_poolpool_id
FK_tbl_user_reports_useruser_id
FK_tbl_user_reports_carriercarrier_id
FK_tbl_user_reports_subscribersubscriber
FK_tbl_user_reports_outboundoutbound_id
directiondirection
```

Comment: yes, the following columns are indexed: user_id, bound_time, direction

Comment: Can you share the EXPLAIN output for your query?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try a compound index on

```
(bound_time, user_id, direction)
```

Contains all the fields you need and can be narrowed by the date range very efficiently.

Comment: (bound_time, user_id, direction) are already indexed, the query seems to speed up if i remove the order by clause

Comment: Are you sure they are indexed in a composite index (not separately)? Also, yes, removing the order by would speed up things immensely, but you would just get ten random results, not the top 10, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If possible redesign your report table to take more advantage of your innodb clustered primary key index.

Here's a simplified example of what i mean:

5 million rows
32K users
126K records in date range

cold runtime (after mysqld restart) = 0.13 seconds

```
create table user_reports
(
bound_time datetime not null,
user_id int unsigned not null,
id int unsigned not null,
direction tinyint unsigned not null default 0,
primary key (bound_time, user_id, id) -- clustered composite PK
)
engine=innodb;


select count(*) as counter from user_reports;

+---------+
| counter |
+---------+
| 5000000 |
+---------+

select count(distinct(user_id)) as counter from user_reports;

+---------+
| counter |
+---------+
|   32000 |
+---------+

select count(*) as counter from user_reports
 where bound_time between '2011-02-01 00:00:00' and '2011-04-30 00:00:00';

+---------+
| counter |
+---------+
|  126721 |
+---------+

select
 t.user_id,
 sum(t.direction = 1) AS num_in,
 sum(t.direction = 0) AS num_out
from
 user_reports t
where
 t.bound_time between '2011-02-01 00:00:00' and '2011-04-30 00:00:00' and 
 t.user_id is not null
group by
 t.user_id
order by
 direction desc
limit 10;

+---------+--------+---------+
| user_id | num_in | num_out |
+---------+--------+---------+
|   17397 |      1 |       1 |
|   14729 |      2 |       1 |
|   20094 |      4 |       1 |
|   19343 |      7 |       1 |
|   24804 |      1 |       2 |
|   14714 |      3 |       2 |
|    2662 |      4 |       3 |
|   16360 |      2 |       3 |
|   21288 |      2 |       3 |
|   12800 |      6 |       2 |
+---------+--------+---------+
10 rows in set (0.13 sec)

explain
select
 t.user_id,
 sum(t.direction = 1) AS num_in,
 sum(t.direction = 0) AS num_out
from
 user_reports t
where
 t.bound_time between '2011-02-01 00:00:00' and '2011-04-30 00:00:00' and 
 t.user_id is not null
group by
 t.user_id
order by
 direction desc
limit 10;

+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  |rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t     | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |255270 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: @darkcolonist: That is what I meant by "composite index for all three columns", although I would probably not make it the primary key seeing that user_id can be null.

Answer (score 1):

As Thilo said add indexes, also instead `tbl_user_reports t` use `tbl_user_reports AS t`, I would move HAVING statement to WHERE to reduce amount of operations.

`WHERE t.user_id IS NOT NULL AND t.bound_time BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-02-28'`

**UPDATE**
For experiment purpose you can try to use like instead of between

`t.bound_time LIKE '2011-02%'`

Comment: One would hope that MySQL is clever enough to figure that out by itself, though.

Comment: I was going to suggest this as it's likely to reduce the search space earlier on in the process. As in, exclude the NULLs as quickly as possible so that the group-by never sees them. Whether this will improve performance depends on the DBMS implementation so you should measure it of course, but this has a better-than-even chance of improving things and very little chance of making it worse. @Thilo, _never_ hope, _always_ measure :-)